# How do I find installed packages that have no install candidate?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, aptitude

I'd like to retrieve a list of installed packages that have no install candidate (e.g., because I removed an apt source file entry). How would I do that on Debian-based systems?

Comment: You could use `apt-show-versions` and grep for `No available version in archive`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Aptitude, search for the `?obsolete` [pattern](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html), possibly with a custom [display format](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s04s01.html#secDisplayFormat).

```
aptitude -F '%p' search '?obsolete'
```

Comment: I knew I should have started learning command-line package management using aptitude instead of apt. Thanks, straightforward and faster than the other answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

This one was updated:

```
for package in $(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/{print $2}'); do
     if ! grep -xq "Package: $package" /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages; then
         echo $package
     fi
done
```

Using apt-cache policy:

```
for package in $(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/{print $2}'); do
    if ! apt-cache policy $package | grep -q '[0-9] http://'; then
        echo $package
    fi
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to care about :i386 packages on systems with multiarch support. Parsing the output of `apt-cache policy <package>` would work, but that would be rather slow I imagine.

Comment: Give me an example of what the output of `apt-cache policy` would look like on your multiarch system.

Comment: The example for such a package with no install candidate...

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/811658/ - but I got another idea: trying to `apt-get download -s` all installed packages.

Comment: Your `apt-cache policy` doesn't help and `apt-get download` doesn't exist in Debian.

Comment: Why doesn't it help? According to the version table, the installed version cannot be retrieved anymore. On "vanilla Debian" it's maybe `install -d` instead of `download` (sorry didn't check). Anyways, I just tried that on an Ubuntu box. It works fine, but is quite slow.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Great, it's much faster than expected. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your packages with

```
sudo apt-get install update
```

In most cases it will solve the issues.If any unmet dependency issues are arises use this one

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```