# How to find out which packages that have no install candidate can be removed? (How to properly clean out such packages?)

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, uninstall

To find packages which have no installation candidate in my current repositories I ran:
`apt-show-versions | grep "No available version in archive"` (as recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29627/how-do-i-find-installed-packages-that-have-no-install-candidate))
I think it would be best if one was notified by the package manager that there are packages that were installed from a repository but are not in any of the current repositories anymore. That would be a (separate) issue with the package-manager though.

The command returned packages such as `libgnome-keyring-common:all`, `bum` and `libgdbm3:amd64`.

Now I'd like to find out which of these I can safely remove. I know that I installed some of those by by installing .deb files and these should not be removed.

I already tried running `sudo apt-cache show libgdbm3`, `sudo apt show libgdbm3`, `sudo dpkg -p libgdbm3` but it only shows (latter command):

```
Package: libgdbm3
Priority: important
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 68
Maintainer: Debian QA Group <packages@qa.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: gdbm
Version: 1.8.3-14
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), dpkg (>= 1.15.4) | install-info
Filename: pool/main/g/gdbm/libgdbm3_1.8.3-14_amd64.deb
Size: 30042
MD5sum: 4bd924fc8be5471a12d1e0204c74d6c3
Description: GNU dbm database routines (runtime version)
Description-md5: 900375b4641d82391c1c951c3b8647f6
Homepage: http://directory.fsf.org/project/gdbm/
Tag: role::shared-lib
SHA256: fbce0e2500aa970ed03665d15822265ff8d31c81927b987ae34e206b9b5ab0b6
```

and not how this package was installed. When I run `sudo apt-get remove gdbm` I get `E: Unable to locate package gdbm`.

How to properly clean out packages with no install candidate? And why are they not automatically removed or prompted to be removed when they got installed via a repo but are not in the current repos anymore? (Seems like this should be done every time repos are changed or an upgrade was done.)

System is Debian10/KDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest marking all such packages as automatically installed:

```
apt-show-versions | awk '/No available version in archive/ { print $1 }' | xargs sudo apt-mark auto
```

Then `apt autoremove` will weed out those which can be removed; you’ll need to check the list and un-mark any packages you want to keep (`apt-mark manual`).

Packages can lose their “automatic” marker in a number of ways; one in particular is if `apt install` is ever used with them, *e.g.* to upgrade them or to try to figure out why they’re held back. Packages without the “automatic” marker won’t be candidates for removal unless another package conflicts with them. Even automatically-installed packages can stick around longer than intended: by default, if another package suggests them, they won’t be removed (which is a weaker dependency than any which would cause a package to be *installed* in the first place, by default).

Comment: The problem with that is that it's also marking packages installed with .deb files for removal (like Zettlr and latest BackInTime). And it doesn't show why/how/when packages were installed. I guess your approach would be unmarking these packages manually.

Comment: Like I said, “you’ll need to check the list and un-mark any packages you want to keep”. Other than the logs in `/var/log/apt`, the system has no memory of why packages were installed or where they were installed from (repositories or local packages).

Comment: I hoped there was a way to see how packages were installed (other than `grep`ing the console history). It would be a very useful feature imo - strange this hasn't been implemented yet. That `apt-show-versions` also shows `gcc-6:amd64` after autoremoving a bunch of packages of which I don't know why & how they were installed (I only `sudo apt-mark manual package` those I knew). Shouldn't this be installed from a repo? And I guess I can remove `[libva1](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libva1)` (in Buster) even though apt autoremove did not prompt to remove it?

Comment: Lastly `apt-mark showmanual` shows lots of packages installed from the repos (like vlc from debian-stable-main) instead of those marked as manual and `apt-mark showhold` shows none. How can one display a list of manual marked packages?

Comment: `gcc-6` isn’t present in Debian 10, that’s why `apt-show-versions` lists it as “No available version in archive”. It would have been installed from the repository on Debian 9, but it’s gone from Debian 10. The same goes for `libva1`. `apt-mark showmanual` does show packages marked as manual — “manual” means that the package was installed explicitly by the user, rather than as a dependency for another package. It has nothing to do with where the package came from.

Comment: Alright, in that case I think I can remove it. Removing it shouldn't cause any problems right? How can I display such packages which were removed since an upgrade and are candidates for removal? (`gcc-6 was already set to automatically installed` but `sudo apt autoremove` does not ask me to remove it.)

Comment: If `apt autoremove` doesn’t offer to remove it, that means that another installed package depends on it, perhaps weakly. Attempting to remove it will tell you what the impact will be and give you a chance to cancel. And yes, it should be safe to remove!

Comment: I don't remember installing any of the other non-GUI packages (like `libasan3`) but found that I installed it along with other packages years ago. So I guess the current way to clean out such unneeded packages is to manually go through the remaining entries of `apt-show-versions` and just checking whether it's likely to be still needed or not...no (semi-)automatic way to identify (& remove) such packages? Okay.

Comment: You could also try `deborphan`. Other than that, ISTR a tool which will build a tree of unused packages, so you can start by deciding whether to keep packages at the top of the tree (thereby quickly deciding the fate of entire branches); but I don’t remember its name off-hand.